# android - fragments sharing listener from calling activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, listeners

What I want to do is to have a tabbed activity with 3 Fragments who share the same Toolbar (from the activity) with a Spinner. I want to update the data of the listview inside each fragment when the user changes the value in the spinner.

I first tried setting the onItemSelectedListener on each fragment, but it did really weird stuff. Then I saw it's a bad idea to set multiple listeners for just the same. So now I have it in the activity. The listener gets called whenever the value is changed, but I need it to tell the fragments that it has been called so they can update their contents.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have a reference to the fragment instances, you can add a method inside the fragment to notify it of the selection change.

```
// inside fragment
public void selectionChanged(int position) {
    // update listView
}


// in the activity
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    fragmentA.selectionChanged(position);
    fragmentB.selectionChanged(position);
    fragmentC.selectionChanged(position);
}
```

In case you're using a `ViewPager` and you don't have a reference to the fragment instances you could use an event bus.

Here are a couple:
[Otto](https://github.com/square/otto)
[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: Is there a way to have them instantiated in the activity and use a ViewPager? I am barely new in Android programming and don't really know how the tabbed activity works (I used the default tabbed activity creator).
Edit: I prefer this solution since it is for a university project and using external libraries might be a problem.

Comment: Yes, you can instantiate the fragments in your activity and pass them to your pager adapter.

Comment: And how do I show (?) the fragments when instantiated within the activity?

Comment: Edit: finally got it working, what I did was what @benito-bertoli , I had to instantiate the 3 fragments inside the activity and pass them to the PagerAdapter which had the list with all the fragments I added. Then implementing the function in the fragment was no problem at all, like the spinner listener in the activity. Thank you!